# How to understand "\appendroman#1#2#3" on page 41 of The TeXbook?

Tags: tex-core, def, expandafter

At the bottom of page 41 of **The TeXbook**, there is a question:

> Define a control sequence `\appendroman` with three parameters such that `\appendroman#1#2#3` defines control sequence `#1` to expand to a control sequence whose name is the name of control sequence `#2` followed by the value of the positive integer `#3` expressed in roman numerals. For example, suppose `\count20` equals 30; then `\appendroman\a\TeX{\count20}` should have the same effect as `\def\a{\TeXxxx}`.

As I see this, I have my answer, which I know is not right, that is `\def\appendroamn#1#2#3{\def#1{\#2#3}}`. The right answer of that book is

```
\def\gobble#1{} % remove one token
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname}}
```

There are so many `\expandafter`s, which make me confused. I know that the first line makes a command `\gobble`, which defines `\gobble{ }` that produces nothing. But how to understand the second and the third line here?

Comment: Are you perhaps going to ask about each of the TeXbook exercise? The code you tried is completely wrong to begin with: it makes no sense and shows you still don't know about tokens.

Comment: I do worry a bit that you are expecting to read _The TeXbook_ in order and understand it on a first pass: that's really not how it's intended to work

Comment: @egreg I think those of you who know better should write a book that explains all the exercises in detail.

Comment: If Knuth's writing style does not suit you, maybe try learning from TeX by Topic?

Comment: I once read that book a little and found it is difficult for me to read too. So, I chose the original one, **The TeXbook**. @user202729

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** My favourite reading about `\expandafter`: [A Tutorial on `\expandafter`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) (TUGboat 9)

---

Let's look at the example: the code

```
\appendroman\a\TeX{\count20}
```

expands to

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string\TeX\romannumeral\count20\endcsname}
```

Now the first `\expandafter` saves `\def` for later: I denote this by putting the token in parentheses:

```
(\def)\expandafter\a\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string\TeX\romannumeral\count20\endcsname}
```

Now there is a further `\expandafter`, which agains saves the next token for later

```
(\def)(\a)\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string\TeX\romannumeral\count20\endcsname}
```

The same game a third time, now that this time the *brace* is saved for later

```
(\def) (\a) ({) \csname\expandafter\gobble\string\TeX\romannumeral\count20\endcsname}
```

Now TeX encounters `\csname` and begins to build a control sequence name out of everything between `\csname` and `\endcsname` (discarding spaces directly after `\csname` but *not* other ones). The expansion of `\csname...\endcsname` is such that *everything* is expanded, until only character tokens remain. The control name derives thus from the expansion of

```
\expandafter\gobble\string\TeX\romannumeral\count20
```

The game goes on: `\expandafter` saves `\gobble` for later, and `\string` returns `\`<sub>12</sub>`T`<sub>12</sub>`e`<sub>12</sub>`X`<sub>12</sub>. But now the `\gobble` kicks in: it removes the following token, namely the backslash (actually the `\escapechar`), so that only `TeX` (all with category code 12) remain. The expansion goes on, and `\romannumeral\count20` returns `xxx` (since `\count20` is assumed to equal 30). So after full expansion between `\csname` and `\endcsname` we have now `TeXxxx`, which builds the control sequence token `\TeXxxx`. But we have still the saved tokens from the previous `\expandafter`:

```
(\def) (\a) ({) \TeXxxx}
```

So TeX now goes back and finds effectively

```
\def\a{\TeXxxx}
```

---

What does now `\a` actually print? Probably nothing. When you write `\a` in your file, this expands to `\TeXxxx`, and now a further peculiarity kicks in. I quote (Exercise 7.7 in the TeX book): "*When `\csname` is used to deﬁne a control sequence for the ﬁrst time, that
control sequence is made equivalent to `\relax` until it is redeﬁned.*" This means that with

```
\appendroman\a\TeX{30}\a
```

nothing is printed, but with

```
\def\TeXxxx{hello}
\appendroman\a\TeX{30}\a
```

you'll find "hello" in your output.

Comment: `\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_appendroman:nnn { \cs_new:Npe #1 { \exp_not:c { \cs_to_str:N #2 \int_to_roman:n { #3 } } } }`

Comment: @egreg Well yes but not quite sure it answers the question ;)

Comment: Why doesn't ``\def\gobble#1{} % remove one token
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname}}
\appendroman\a\TeX{30}
\a`` produce `TEX30`, but `\TeX30` can?

Comment: Because `\appendroman\a\TeX{30}` just defines to macro `\a` to expand to `\TeXxxx`, and since this has been defined my `\csname` it has the default meaning of `\relax`, so it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @campa `\TeXxxx` will produce `TEXxxx`, but `\a` can't. Why does `\def\a{\TeX{xxx}}` can make `\a` produce `TEXxxx`? I don't understand the effects of `\relax` here.

Comment: No, `\TeXxxx` does *not* produce `TEXxxx`, at least not with this code. With `\def\a{\TeX{xxx}}` the expansion of ``\a` is simply `\TeX{xxx}`, which prints TEX followed by xxx.

Comment: @wipet Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4):

The following lists a sequence of steps (important: those are not expansion steps as they are done by TeX, these are more processing steps done internally by TeX).

What's important to note is that all this (except for the last step, doing `\def`) happens as a single step of expansion. That's the case because `\expandafter` expands in a single step to the result of the expansion of the second token following it, removing the `\expandafter` from the stream. Also `\csname` expands in a single step, expanding everything expandable until it hits `\endcsname` (or throwing a low-level error if it hits something that after expansion is not a character token) leaving its result in the stream.

So after your definition

```
\def\gobble#1{} % remove one token
\def\appendroman#1#2#3%
  {%
    \expandafter\def
    \expandafter#1%
    \expandafter{%
      \csname
        \expandafter\gobble
        \string#2\romannumeral#3%
      \endcsname
    }%
  }
```

We'll take a look at a single usage of that macro. In the following I have as a format the first line being a comment summarising the current step, then maybe deferred information, then as uncommented lines the input stream which TeX examines.

```
% step 1: simple expansion
\appendroman\a\TeX{30}

% step 2: defer \expandafter<TOKEN>
\expandafter\def
\expandafter\a
\expandafter{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 3: defer \expandafter<TOKEN>
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def
\expandafter\a
\expandafter{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 4: defer \expandafter<TOKEN>
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a
\expandafter{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 5: start \csname-expansion
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 6: defer \expandafter<TOKEN>
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname
    \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 7: \string (turning the token \TeX into four tokens of category 12)
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\gobble
    \string\TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 8: inner expandafter-chain done, put back
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\gobble
    \TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 9: \gobble one token (category 12 \)
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname
    \gobble
    \TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 10: defer unexpandable tokens inside \csname
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname
    TeX\romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 11: \romannumeral expansion, start scanning for a number
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
    \romannumeral30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 12: scanning number
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
% \romannumeral-expansion: \romannumeral
    30%
  \endcsname
}

% step 13: scanning number
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
% \romannumeral-expansion: \romannumeral 3
    0%
  \endcsname
}

% step 14: scanning number
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
% \romannumeral-expansion: \romannumeral 30
  \endcsname
}

% step 15: \romannumeral hitting \endcsname, end of number put back result
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
% \romannumeral-expansion: \romannumeral 30
  \endcsname
}

% step 16: defer unexpandable tokens inside \csname
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeX
    xxx%
  \endcsname
}

% step 17: \endcsname (stop \csname building, put back result)
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
% \csname-expansion: \csname TeXxxx
  \endcsname
}

% step 18: expandafter-chain done, put back
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a\expandafter{%
  \TeXxxx
}

% step 19: expandafter-chain done, put back
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def\expandafter\a
  {%
  \TeXxxx
}

% step 20: expandafter-chain done, put back
% Deferred expandafter-chain: \expandafter\def
  \a{%
  \TeXxxx
}

% step 21: expandafter-chain done, put back
\def\a{%
  \TeXxxx
}

% step 22: execute \def (we don't examine the collecting of \def's arguments here)
% assign meaning \a=macro:->\TeXxxx.
%% done
```

Comment: What will happen if change ``\def\gobble#1{} % remove one token
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname}}`` to ``\def\gobble#1{} % remove one token
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1
{\csname\expandafter\gobble\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname}}``? Why should this `\expandafter` be added?

Comment: @Y.zeng if you put a space after `#1` you'll try to expand that space with your `\expandafter`-chain and the expansion stops there, putting everything back, and your definition will be equivalent to `\def#1 {\csname\expandafter\gobble\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname}`. If you remove that space and don't insert that other `\expandafter` you'll try to expand the brace instead (which still doesn't expand and everything will be put back, `\expandafter` only cares for tokens not macro-arguments, and `}` is a token).

Comment: If I remove the space and don;t insert that `\expandafter`, the `{` will cause them be put back, so things go wrong. Right?

Comment: If you don't insert another `\expandafter` the chain is broken at that point, whatever follows `#1` will be expanded once (if its expandable, else it'll remain unchanged), and the deferred `\expandafter`-chain will be put back with the `\expandafter`s removed. So yes, it'll break and things won't be right.

Comment: @Skillmon As a penance, you have to upvote my answer. 

Comment: @egreg done (and now, I shall read it :P)

Answer (score 4):

There are already excellent explanations. I'd like to underline a possible weakness of Knuth's solution, which assumes `\escapechar` points to an actual character. The solution would fail if `\escapechar` is outside the character range, from 0 to 255 for TeX (extended to `0x10FFFF` for Unicode engines), because `\gobble` would eat a character from the control sequence name.

Here's a solution free of the problem, because `\escapechar` is set to minus one before doing the business, but inside a group.

```
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{%
  % #1 = cs to be defined
  % #2 = cs to be appended a Roman numeral
  % #3 = integer (implicit or explicit)
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1 \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{%
    \csname\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname
  }%
}

\appendroman\a\TeX{30} \show\a

\count20=18

\appendroman\a\TeX{\count20} \show\a

\showthe\escapechar
```

On the console one gets

```
> \a=macro:
->\TeXxxx .
l.11 \appendroman\a\TeX{30} \show\a

?
> \a=macro:
->\TeXxviii .
l.15 \appendroman\a\TeX{\count20} \show\a

?
> 92.
l.17 \showthe\escapechar
```

which shows that the working is as expected and also that the value of `\escapechar` is restored after the business.

Note the ***important*** space after `-1`. If one forgets it, the assignment to `\escapechar` would happen only after the `\expandafter` chain has performed its actions. But, anyway, a space after a constant is ***good practice***.

The trick is that the `\expandafter` before `\endgroup` starts the expansions eventually triggering the expansion of `\csname`, which does full expansion until finding `\endcsname`. In the first example, the input stream after `\expandafter`, `\csname` and `\rommannumeral` have done their work would be

```
\endgroup\def\a{\TeXxxx}
```

The left-over `\endgroup` will restore the value of `\escapechar` as it was when the group started.

Alternative solution with a single `\expandafter`, but with `\noexpand` twice:

```
\def\appendroman#1#2#3{%
  % #1 = cs to be defined
  % #2 = cs to be appended a Roman numeral
  % #3 = integer (implicit or explicit)
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#1{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#2\romannumeral#3\endcsname
  }}\x
}
```

The same with `expl3`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \appendroman #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_set:Npe #1 { \exp_not:c { \cs_to_str:N #2 \int_to_roman:n { #3 } } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I'd highlight that the space after `-1` for the `\escapechar` setting is required so that the number scanning ends and the `\expandafter` is only applied after the `\escapechar` was changed.

Comment: @Skillmon Agreed!

Comment: What is the meaning of `extended to 0x10FFFF for Unicode engines` and `cs`? Is a group one token?  Why did you add `\expandafter` before the end of the group in `\begingroup\escapechar=-1 \expandafter\endgroup`?